# How to make a website that redirects to a random link on a list?

Tags: redirect

I'm wanting to know how to make a redirect a simple way.

I know nothing about code (Sorry for my ignorance) but I want to learn.

So I want to make a website that only redirects, so when someone opens it will get redirected to another website.

The tricky thing here is that I want the website to select a random link in a list I will provide, so I thought I could do it on a free website creator (wix.com) and I wanted to know if someone could help me do the code for me.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need Javascript and HTML for do this.
HTML just do static things, so you will need create a list with Javascript and then modify the link on html page.

Just add this to the Head on your HTML file:

```js
<script>
    window.location.replace('http://www.reddit.com')
</script>
```

That will redirect to Reddit as soon as you open your html file.
I recommend that you use the "IF / Else" or "for" function to redirect to different websites each time you open your web page, because you said that you are learning, so go slow. Just study Javascript or Dart and you can do whatever you want on your site.